# How does the copy and paste mechanism work and is it a standard design pattern as in GoF?

Tags: design-patterns

How does the current copy and paste work on a computer?  Such as being able to copy some formatted text together with an image, and then when pasted to a text editor, it will intelligently paste only ASCII or UTF-8 text, while if pasted to some webapps or Microsoft Word or Pages on a Mac, it will paste the text together with the formatting info as well as the image.  (Is this actually one of the GoF Design Pattern or a design pattern that is well defined that actually has a name to it?)

Comment: Are you simply asking how it's possible for the paste operation to produce different data depending on the target application, or are you asking us what design patterns (if any) Windows/Mac/Linux have in their codebases for this? (the former is on-topic and easy to answer, the latter is off-topic)

Comment: I am actually interested in both.  I have rephrased the question to make it more general

Comment: Whether or not any specific design pattern as described in the book factors into it depends entirely on the implementation.  Design patters are just names given to common ways of solving certain problems; they're not something you snap together to build programs.

Comment: Copy/paste is operating system specific. The programmers of this functionality in each operating system may or may not have used a GoF design pattern when they were programming it.

Comment: right, it can be specific, just that when understanding how something works, when I found out the DOM level 2 event handling is just the chain of responsibility (which I didn't know too much about before), then everything becomes quite clear

Comment: I clicked on this question to learn about the new GoF pattern “copy & paste”. Well, I didn't…

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is that when you start a drag operation, the application whose data you're dragging will give the operating system that data *in one or more specific formats*. Then, the application you drop the data on will ask the OS if it has data *in one or more specific formats*. Thus, when dropping "the same data" on two different applications results in two different pieces of data appearing, that simply means those two target applications made different choices out of the range of data formats provided by the source application.

For maximum interoperability, it's generally encouraged to provide your drag data in as many formats as possible. The OS might even "fill in" some extra formats for you where possible, or allow you to register your own custom data formats in addition to the standard ones it provides.

Since I feel like citing a source with some more concrete system-specific details, [here is the MSDN page on clipboard data formats in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Registered_Clipboard_Formats). I assume Mac and Linux have much of the same functionality.

As for design patterns, I'm not aware of anything you could call a "design pattern" that would be inherently appropriate for implementing this functionality. And I have no idea whether the big three operation systems actually contain any in their implementations.

Comment: This is largely [how the pasteboard works in OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbConcepts.html), too.